# Height of parent element containing only floats collapse to nothing. How to fix it?

Tags: css

One of the more bewildering things about working with floats is how they can affect the element that contains them (their "parent" element). If this parent element contained nothing but floated elements, the height of it would literally collapse to nothing. This isn't always obvious if the parent doesn't contain any visually noticeable background, but it is important to be aware of.

I have background-image in parent element and 2 sub float elements. As above description says, its (parent element)height collapses to zero whenever it has only float elements. How can I fix it? I dont want to add height or any content to parent tag. I want height of parent element to auto-increase in accordance to content of floating elements? How can I achieve it?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful to us.

Comment: Here is a fiddle - outerdiv with background and two floats. Can you explain what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/Xq2We/

Comment: Search in google about *clearfix* There are huge amounts of references

Answer (score 0):

add

```
#parent{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

or clear floats using available techniques

Comment: Wow! it Worked. Can you explain how it did it?

Comment: Not only is this no longer the accepted solution for clearing floats (see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) but this answer would definitely have benefited from some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you have different ways to manage floatting element and include them in the flow. Parents or aside elements needs their layout to be trigger in a way, it calculates room/space used by floatting elements.
here is a few ways that you can apply to your snippet :

```
    /* different ways to play with layout */
    .outerdiv:before { /* add classname in document to be abble to relat it to css rules applied , demo purpose */
        content:attr(class);
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:-1.2em;
        background:yellow;
    }
    .outerdiv { /* demo purpose , we stack them */
        clear:both;
        margin:1em auto;
    }
/* here we go ========================================= */
    .clearafter:after {
        content:'';
        display:block;
        clear:both;
    }
    .displayib {display:inline-block;}
    .displaytb {display:table;}
    .overflowh {overflow:hidden;}
    .overflowa {overflow:auto;}
    .overflowv {overflow:visible;} /* defaut, doesn't trigger anything */
    .float {float:left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xq2We/1/ you can see each possibilities and see what it involves as result.

To go further and understand better you can read this : http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/